# Laravel 5.2- stylesheet(CSS) not working

Tags: css, laravel-5

i need help in my problem, i'm using ajax to get data with JSON using pagination my problem is my stylesheet in the second page not working but the class (Bootstrap) working please help

Comment: You're being a little vague. Can you show the code that's not working, and what you expect it to do?

Comment: What changes does your ajax call make ? The entire page ? Post the code, its hard to figure where the problem is !

Comment: Thanks Jordan Carter, Piya Desai i fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

Have you right clicked the webpage and selected 'View page source'?

- check whether the path is correct that calls the CSS stylesheet.

Have you used the proper blade syntax to link the stylesheet?

- HTML::style('css/stylesheet.css')

The following thread might help you which also applies to laravel 5.2

https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/linking-to-css-and-js-laravel-51

Comment: I fix the Thank you so much